# How to insert values into a table depending of the XML file attribute with xQuery in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, xml, stored-procedures, xquery-sql

I want to insert the first attributes of the XML always in the same table, but depending of the value of last the XML attributes I have to insert to another table.

I have in mind to something like this. But obviously it is wrong.

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spCargarDatosCC]
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

-- VARIABLES --
DECLARE @CCobro xml

BEGIN TRY
    SELECT @CCobro = CC
    FROM OPENROWSET (Bulk 'D:\Base de datos\FacturacionMunicipal_BD\Base de Datos\XML\Concepto_de_Cobro.xml', Single_BLOB) AS CCobro(CC)

    INSERT INTO CCobro (ID, Nombre, TasaInteresMoratorio, DiaEmisionRecibo, QDiasVencimiento, EsImpuesto, EsRecurrente, EsFijo, TipoCC, Activo)
    SELECT c.value('@id','INT') AS ID
        , c.value('@Nombre','VARCHAR(100)') AS Nombre
        , c.value('@TasaInteresMoratoria','DECIMAL(10,2)') AS TasaInteresMoratorio
        , c.value('@DiaCobro','TINYINT') AS DiaEmisionRecibo
        , c.value('@QDiasVencimiento','TINYINT') AS QDiasVencimiento
        , c.value('@EsImpuesto','VARCHAR(10)') AS EsImpuesto 
        , c.value('@EsRecurrente','VARCHAR(10)') AS EsRecurrente  
        , c.value('@EsFijo','VARCHAR(10)') AS EsFijo  
        , c.value('@TipoCC','VARCHAR(10)') AS TipoCC
        , 1 AS Activo

        -- the code from above to here works as I want

        -- THIS PART IS WHAT I WANT TO INSERT CONDITIONALLY 

        if(c.value('@Monto', 'MONEY') != NULL) then
            insert into CCobro_MontoFijo (ID, MontoFijo) --CCobro_MontoFijo is a table that references CCobro
            SELECT c.value('@id', 'INT') AS ID
            , c.value('@Monto', 'MONEY') AS MontoFijo
        if(c.value('@ValorM3', 'MONEY') != NULL) then
            insert into CCobro_ConsumoAgua(ID, ConsumoM3)  --CCobro_ConsumoAgua is a table that references CCobro
            SELECT c.value('@id', 'INT') AS ID
            , c.value('@ValorM3', 'MONEY') AS ConsumoM3
        if(c.value('@ValorPorcentaje', 'REAL') != NULL) then
            insert into CCobro_InteresMoratorio(ID, Valor_Porcentual) --CCobro_InteresMoratorio is a table that references CCobro
            SELECT c.value('@id', 'INT') AS ID
            , c.value('@ValorPorcentaje', 'REAL') AS Valor_Porcentual

    FROM @CCobro.nodes('/Conceptos_de_Cobro/conceptocobro') AS t(c);



END TRY

BEGIN CATCH
    return @@ERROR * -1
END CATCH

END
```

XML File that I want to read. Notice that the last attributes sometimes are NULL, because they depends on TipoCC atributte.

```
<Conceptos_de_Cobro>
    <conceptocobro id="1" Nombre="Agua" DiaCobro="25" QDiasVencimiento="4" EsImpuesto="No" EsRecurrente="Si" EsFijo="No" TasaInteresMoratoria="5.2" TipoCC="CC Consumo" Monto="" ValorM3="500" ValorPorcentaje="" />
    <conceptocobro id="2" Nombre="Patente Licores" DiaCobro="8" QDiasVencimiento="12" EsImpuesto="Si" EsRecurrente="No" EsFijo="No" TasaInteresMoratoria="2.6" TipoCC="CC Fijo" Monto="50000" ValorM3="" ValorPorcentaje="" />
    <conceptocobro id="3" Nombre="impuesto Propiedad" DiaCobro="8" QDiasVencimiento="12" EsImpuesto="Si" EsRecurrente="No" EsFijo="Si" TasaInteresMoratoria="1.5" TipoCC="CC Porcentual" Monto="" ValorM3="" ValorPorcentaje="0.25" />
    <conceptocobro id="4" Nombre="Recolectar Basura" DiaCobro="4" QDiasVencimiento="5" EsImpuesto="No" EsRecurrente="Si" EsFijo="Si" TasaInteresMoratoria="2.2" TipoCC="CC Fijo" Monto="3000" ValorM3="" ValorPorcentaje="" />
    <conceptocobro id="5" Nombre="Mantenimiento de Parques" DiaCobro="3" QDiasVencimiento="7" EsImpuesto="Si" EsRecurrente="Si" EsFijo="Si" TasaInteresMoratoria="0.87" TipoCC="CC Fijo" Monto="970" ValorM3="" ValorPorcentaje="" />
    <conceptocobro id="6" Nombre="Reconexion de Agua" DiaCobro="15" QDiasVencimiento="10" EsImpuesto="No" EsRecurrente="No" EsFijo="Si" TasaInteresMoratoria="3.8" TipoCC="CC Fijo" Monto="780" ValorM3="" ValorPorcentaje="" />
    <conceptocobro id="7" Nombre="Impuesto a la Renta" DiaCobro="5" QDiasVencimiento="15" EsImpuesto="Si" EsRecurrente="Si" EsFijo="No" TasaInteresMoratoria="12.6" TipoCC="CC Porcentual" Monto="" ValorM3="" ValorPorcentaje="0.15" />
    <conceptocobro id="8" Nombre="Mantenimiento de Parques" DiaCobro="7" QDiasVencimiento="6" EsImpuesto="No" EsRecurrente="Si" EsFijo="Si" TasaInteresMoratoria="0.32" TipoCC="CC Fijo" Monto="7850" ValorM3="" ValorPorcentaje="" />
    <conceptocobro id="9" Nombre="Aseo de sitios Publico" DiaCobro="1" QDiasVencimiento="10" EsImpuesto="No" EsRecurrente="Si" EsFijo="Si" TasaInteresMoratoria="7.8" TipoCC="CC Fijo" Monto="580" ValorM3="" ValorPorcentaje="" />
</Conceptos_de_Cobro>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each `INSERT` statement into a different table should be SQL statement on its own.

For each `if ... then` statement you need to use the following approach.

The `WHERE` clause will take care of missing values after the conversion into `MONEY` data type inside the CTE.

> SQL

```
;WITH rs AS
(
    SELECT c.value('@id','INT') AS ID
        , c.value('@Monto','MONEY') AS MontoFijo
    FROM @CCobro.nodes('/Conceptos_de_Cobro/conceptocobro') AS t(c)
)
INSERT INTO CCobro_MontoFijo (ID, MontoFijo)
SELECT ID, MontoFijo FROM rs
WHERE rs.Monto > 0;
```